# Postfix after insalling quickly?

Tags: postfix, quickly

After attempting to install quickly with:

```
sudo apt-get install quickly python-quickly-widgets
```

I got a postfix (mail daemon) configuration screen. Why do I need it to use quickly and how should I configure it? I read/write mail on my browser (gmail...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postfix is a *mail transfer agent*, it's used to send email from within your computer system (email is inherently built into every unix-like operating system). This is sometimes used to record notifications for system administrators (i.e. an email to the 'root' user account) and things like that.

[image]

In short, you can safely select **`No Configuration`**. You absolutely don't need to worry about it.

The reason why postfix was configured was that `bsd-mailx` depends on it, which in turn is a dependency of `devscripts`, which is installed as part of the debian build system.